# Cannot filter on subsites / values in a list / Modern PnP Search

Tags: search, filter, pnp-framework

I have this list :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2sap.png)

and I want in my search page , to display results and enable filtering on the subsites mentionned in this list
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg6KK.png)
I have here a filter on the SiteName which display all the subsites , I should have only Program and Program22 and when I choose Program he should display all the results in this site of Program. Any help please ?

I have here a filter on the SiteName which display all the subsites , I should have only Program and Program22 and when I choose Program he should display all the results in this site of Program